# How to use Spring 4 convertPropertyValue (for reading encrypted values)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

We are using spring 4 place holder feature

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:/configs/*.properties,classpath:/configs/specific/*-config.properties" />
```

The property files:

```
##sample.properties
user=admin
password=123
```

We try to encrypt the password in the property file. So the property file will be

```
##sample.properties
user=admin
password=ENC(RE%%$XC)
```

I found that the spring has forecast this. As mentioned in http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/PropertyResourceConfigurer.html the `convertPropertyValue` method has been documented as:

> Convert the given property value from the properties source to the
>   value which should be applied.
>
> The default implementation simply returns the original value. Can be
>   overridden in subclasses, for example to detect encrypted values and
>   decrypt them accordingly.

But I don't know how to use it ?! I tried to define a new bean:

```
    <bean class="foo.bar.security.DecryptPropertyConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:/configs/*.properties</value>
            <value>classpath:/configs/bsi/*-config.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>  
    </bean>
```

And

```
public class DecryptPropertyConfigurer extends PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer {

    @Override
    protected String convertPropertyValue(String originalValue){
        //if value is between ENC() then decrypt it
        //return originalValue or decrypted value;
    }

}
```

When I set break point at `convertPropertyValue` it seems that it is never called.

The http://romiawasthy.blogspot.com/2012/02/encryptdecrpt-properties-in-spring.html contains some good info but did not help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in spring https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8928.
As a commented workaround there, one can use `doProcessProperties` as

```
protected void doProcessProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactoryToProcess, final StringValueResolver valueResolver) {

    super.doProcessProperties(beanFactoryToProcess,
            new StringValueResolver() {
                @Override
                public String resolveStringValue(String strVal) {
                    return convertPropertyValue(valueResolver.resolveStringValue(strVal));
                }
            }
    );
}
```

Credits to Michael Gallag

Comment: Can you please explain more elaborately how to apply this workaround?